# Make executable solution containing several projects

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution named Linguistic in which there are 4 projects. Three are Kinect Libraries and one is the main project which is dependable on those 3 projects. the main project has WPF forms. I want to make an executable file for the complete project.  I have gone through many links but none of them worked for me. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Please start by posting the types of each project. Do you have any executable project? This could be a Console application, a WinForms project, a WPF project, etc

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I have edited my question have a look

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at your latest edit:

> Three are Kinect Libraries and one is the main project which is dependable on those 3 projects. the main project has WPF forms

If the main project is a WPF project, then this is what you need to do (for getting an .exe file that doesn't need to be installed):

1. Switch compilation mode from Debug to Release (so that debug information is not shown to the end user)
2. Compile the WPF project
3. Right-click on the WPF project and select "Open Folder in File Explorer"
4. Open bin\release
5. There you have the .exe file that you can open and use, supposing that you don't have any file dependencies that aren't attached to the file itself.

Answer (score -1):

You should have an executable project (console or whatever) then you should set such project as the default startup project and that should do it.

The exception to this would be an `MVC`/`asp.net` project which generates a different structure as it is meant to be deployed in a web server (typically `IIS`)

Comment: How would setting the startup project solve anything related to deployment?

Comment: Yes by doing that you're telling `msbuild.exe` (the .sln compiler) that it is the `main` project. So it knows how to output it. if you want more information about it you can search for help about `MSbuild` the language of the solutions and projects.

Comment: "So it knows how to output it"? That makes absolutely no sense. The project .csproj is the file that contains information on the type of the output for that specific project. Look at a project' properties > Application > Output type

Comment: yes @cFrozenDeath the project type comes from the csproj file, but the sln file need to have a startup project so `msbuild` knows how to output it (the solution) imagine you have a console and a windows form project in the same solution. How can it know what you actually want to output? That's where the *start up project* enters the scene

Comment: One thing is what it builds, another completely unrelated thing is what it starts up. It builds everything in the way it's specified in the project file, and then decides what to start depending on the start up project. This doesn't influence the build project; otherwise a solution with library-only files would always compile differently "because it doesn't know what to start"

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I think we are saying the same, but in different terms.